# How do I convert a java.util.Set[Field] to an Array[Field] in scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

I am doing some operations using Reflections, between I got to convert a `java.util.Set[Field]` to `Array[Field]` and I tried `.toArray` but getting `Array[AnyRef]` instead of `Array[Field]`.

Can anyone help me out in converting `java.util.Set` to Array preserving the type information?

I'm using version 2.11.7 of Scala

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `import java.lang.reflect.Field; def test(in: Set[Field]): Array[Field] = in.toArray`

Comment: @ 0__ ... I am getting type mismatch error since it is java.util.Set

Comment: @Jet You should add that to the question.

Comment: I recommend to use Scala collections not Java collections

Comment: @0__ ..Actually my annotation is in Java. So I am getting Java collections.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella may have guessed right, but it would be a lot easier if you showed us the code

Comment: @Paul ...   val reflections = new Reflections("Test");  res = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation);   I was stuck with res here.

Comment: Ta. Better to edit it into the question, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arrays in Java are not generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149904/collection-and-toarray-in-scala), so when you convert from a Java collection it will produce an `Array[Object]`.

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray()) of `toArray` in `java.util.Set` we find two variations of the method

> `Object[] toArray()`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this set.

and

> `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this set; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.

You're currently using the first variation, but you can use the second one by passing an array of the correct type as argument.

This is a "workaround" used by Java in order to produce an array of the correct type.

Here's an example

```
import java.util.HashSet
import java.lang.reflect.Field

val set = new HashSet[Field]
val arr1 = set.toArray // Array[Object]
val arr2 = set.toArray(Array[Field]()) // Array[Field]
```

Another viable option is to convert your `java.util.Set` into a scala `Set`, which provides a "smarter" `toArray` method:

```
import java.util.HashSet
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val set = new HashSet[Field]
val arr = set.toSet.toArray // Array[Field]
```